# How can i fill color for dataseries below or above the threshold using Flot?

Tags: flot

How to fill color below or above the threshold. currently threshold plugin changes the line of the color but i need to fill the color on the dataseries  (eg: below : 5 or above :5 ) when the line is drawing on the canvas using flot line chart. can anyone suggest me. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying your fill color doesn't change above/below a certain threshold, or that you only want to show fill if it is above/below a certain threshold? If its the former, this works for me just by setting fill to true in the series options:

```
$.plot("#placeholder", [{
    data: d1,
    threshold: {
        below: 5,
        color: "rgb(200, 20, 30)"
    }}], {
    series: {
        lines: {
            show: true,
            fill: true
        }
    }
});
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ringstaff/frEPW/) for working example.